# Rspec test of Rails with Capybara fails when before(:all) use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Hello I am newbie of **Rails** and now trying to make a **simple tweeting application**.

I wrote a simple test and tried to use `before(:all)` because I **don't** want to visit page **each time**, but the test doesn't keep the visit page object.

Off course when I use `before(:each)` the test success, but when `it` increase to a large number, I suppose the time of test increase, too.

How can I write this test with `before(:all)`? Thanks for your kindness.

```
# /spec/requests/tweet_pages.spec
require 'spec_helper'

describe "TweetPages" do
  describe "GET /tweet_pages" do

    before(:each) {visit tweets_path} # this line pass test but...
    #before(:all) {visit tweets_path} # next line fails in second it test. 

    subject {page}
    context do
      its(:status_code) {should == 200}
      it {should have_selector 'input'}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken before(:all) runs for all examples within a given describe or context block. In this case, your examples are in their own context block. If you would remove the context block the tests should pass. Otherwise you could add the before(:all) block to the describe or context block you want the before(:all) to have access to.

N.B. It is also recommended to add an after(:all) block to save yourself from the trouble before(:all) can give you. In general, using before(:all) isn't really recommended.

Answer (score 1):

- `before(:each)` runs once for each `it` statement.
- `before(:all)` runs once for each `context` or `describe` block that it's in.

Trying to force `before(:all)` in your case would be counter-productive, but one approach would be to store the result in a `@@class_variable` and later reuse it in your subject.